# Undefined reference to wrapped function with -Wl,--wrap

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, linker, wrapper

I am running RHEL 6.2 using GCC 4.4.6-3. I am unit testing some legacy code and am trying to wrap functions with with `-Wl`,`--wrap=function`. Where function might be system calls like `close`, or `malloc`, but are mostly going to be other functions defined in my linked object files.

My test, check_GetRequestID.c, goes something like:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int __wrap_getpid()
{
   return 10; 
}
int main(void)
{
    int x = API_GetRequestID();
    return 0;

}
```

`API_GetRequestID()` calls `getpid()` so I wrap it into something carefully defined for *unit-testing*.

The compilation command is:

> gcc -m64 -pthread -DLITTLEEND -fPIC -I. -Iother/include/folders -Wall -Wformat -DFIU_ENABLE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -DLINUX -Wpointer-arith -pthread -c check_GetRequestID.c
>
> gcc -m64 -pthread -DLITTLEEND -fPIC -I. -Iother/include/folders -Wall -Wformat -DFIU_ENABLE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -DLINUX -Wpointer-arith -pthread -L. -Lother/lib/paths -lcrypt -lutil -Wl,--wrap=getpid -Wl,--wrap=otherfunctions object.o object2.o ... -o check_GetRequestID

On the linking command I get an error for every function that calls the wrapped functions. If a function in `object2.o` calls `getpid()` then it throws undefined reference for `__wrap_getpid` in `object2.o`. This includes `API_GetRequestID`, which is the function I am trying to *unit-test*.

Any suggestions on changes to the the source or make files which will allow the functions I'm unit testing to call `__wrap_getpid` when they call `getpid()`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just define a function with the exact same prototype as getpid() itself. That way the *dynamic* linker will find your definition first and stop searching for it in linked libraries.

That strategy might not work though if the code using getpid() resides in a dynamic library.

Comment: I think `getpid()` is in a dynamic library, its defined in unistd.h.

Comment: @user1437652: it is, but I said that this technique might not work if code *using* `getpid()` (i.e. `API_GetRequestID` in your case) resides in a dynamic library.